# Saving a chart in VS Code - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using a medical dataset based on TB, where it collects data and places them into different tables. It computes for the rate, population, cases, etc. Everything ran fine up until the last line of code, where I tried to convert this data into a chart and save it to my screenshots. When I ran this code in VS Code, it gave me multiple errors in my terminal. I suspect it is unable to find the path to my screenshots. Can someone give me a clue as to why this is happening?

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import os

current_path = os.getcwd()
print(current_path)
    
base_url = "https://github.com/byuidatascience/data4python4ds/raw/master/data-raw/"
table1 = pd.read_csv("{}table1/table1.csv".format(base_url))
table2 = pd.read_csv("{}table2/table2.csv".format(base_url))
table3 = pd.read_csv("{}table3/table3.csv".format(base_url))
table4a = pd.read_csv("{}table4a/table4a.csv".format(base_url))
table4b = pd.read_csv("{}table4b/table4b.csv".format(base_url))
table5 = pd.read_csv("{}table5/table5.csv".format(base_url), dtype = 'object')
print(table1)
table1 = table1.assign(rate = lambda x: x.cases / x.population * 1000)
print(table1)
table1 = (table1.
        groupby('year').
        agg(n = ('cases', 'sum')).
        reset_index())
print(table1)
base_chart = (alt.Chart(table1).
        encode(alt.X('year'), alt.Y('cases'), detail = 'country'))

chart = base_chart.mark_line() + base_chart.encode(color = 'country').mark_circle()

chart.save(current_path"/screenshots/altair_table1.png")
```

See the above for details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a syntax error in your `chart.save()` line. Instead of using `current_path"/screenshots/altair_table1.png",` you should use `os.path.join(current_path, "screenshots", "altair_table1.png")` to correctly join the path components.

Here's the corrected line:

```
chart.save(os.path.join(current_path, "screenshots", "altair_table1.png"))
```

Working code

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import os
current_path = os.getcwd()
print(current_path)
    
base_url = "https://github.com/byuidatascience/data4python4ds/raw/master/data-raw/"
table1 = pd.read_csv("{}table1/table1.csv".format(base_url))
table2 = pd.read_csv("{}table2/table2.csv".format(base_url))
table3 = pd.read_csv("{}table3/table3.csv".format(base_url))
table4a = pd.read_csv("{}table4a/table4a.csv".format(base_url))
table4b = pd.read_csv("{}table4b/table4b.csv".format(base_url))
table5 = pd.read_csv("{}table5/table5.csv".format(base_url), dtype = 'object')
print(table1)
table1 = table1.assign(rate = lambda x: x.cases / x.population * 1000)
print(table1)
#table1 = (table1.groupby('year').agg(n = ('cases', 'sum')).reset_index())
#print(table1)
base_chart = (alt.Chart(table1).
encode(alt.X('year'), alt.Y('cases'), detail = 'country'))

chart = base_chart.mark_line() + base_chart.encode(color = 'country').mark_circle()

chart.save(os.path.join(current_path, "screenshots", "altair_table1.png"))
```

[image]

Comment: That didn't work; is it possible that it's an issue with VS code?

Comment: Iss is not with vscode are you having same error or different error

Comment: same error occurring

Comment: updated working code